# Proof of Convexity of log det

Tags: matrices, convex-analysis

Prove or disprove. Let $X$ and $Y$ be positive semidefinite matrices of size $M$ and $K$, respectively. Further , let $A$ be any $M\times K$ complex matrix. Then, the function $$-\log\det(I + XAYA^H)$$ is (jointly) convex in $X$ and $Y$.

Note. If it helps, $X$ and $Y$ can be further restricted to being diagonal.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:**
$$\log\det M= \text{tr}(\log M)$$
Here, $M=I+XAYA^H$ is surely positive-definite. Also note that:
$$\log(I+X)=\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{(-1)^{n+1}}{n}X^n$$

Comment: @ polfosol , $M$ is not hermitian and consequently not positive definite. When $M$ is complex $\log(\det(M))\not= tr(\log(M))$. In general, your last equality is false because  the associated series does not converge.

Comment: @loupblanc The OP didn't mention anything about complex numbers. So I assumed we are dealing with real matrices. In general, we can write $\log(I+X)$ either in the above form or $\log X+\log(I+X^{-1})$ based on the value of $X$. In either case, we would end up with infinite series

Comment: Thank you for your reply, @postofol. I do not understand, though, how the infinite series can be used to proof the convexity of the original expression. Could you please be more explicit in your hint? Thanks.

Comment: @lou blanc. I believe that by applying Sylvester'd determinant identity, M can be made Hermitian. Hence, the hint applies.

Comment: @user373117 From the information you gave us, this was the best I could do. I mean your question is unclear (note that they have flagged your question because of the lack of details). Please clarify your question and tell us exactly what you mean and what you want to achieve. Maybe then I would be able to help more.

Comment: @ user373117 , Firstly, consider the case $A=I$. Then $f(X,Y)=-\log(\det(I+XY))$; since $X,Y>0$, the eigenvalues of $XY$ are $>0$ and $f(X,Y)=-tr(\log(I+XY))$ (as polfosol wrote). Show that this function is jointly convex and I vote to reopen.

Comment: @ user37311 , with "prove or disprove", your question is better written. Indeed, let $f:(x,y)\in (0,+\infty)\times (0,+\infty)\rightarrow -\log(1+xy)$; then $f$ is convex only on the subconvex $\{(x,y)|x>0,y>0,xy>1\}$.